# Android Broadcast Receiver battery life every 10 mins or change, can it go in its own thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, broadcastreceiver

I would like to write an application (for research) that makes a timestamp every time the battery level changes. If I can't do that, I want to make it so it takes a battery reading every 10 or so minutes.

I have this `BroadcastReceiver` code but I am not sure where to put it.

My application keeps crashing with the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000000 (has extras) } in com.mdog.datareceive.Receive$1@43c9cd10

In the `onCreate` of my activity I spawn 3 AsyncTask threads that do stuff in the background. Where would be a good place to put the broadcast receiver?

I have tried in the `onCreate` and I have tried in a new method that gets called by one of the background tasks. I think the problem might be that the function the `BroadcastRecevier` code is in might be ending prematurely?

Is there anyway I could put it in its own thread so that it just waits for broadcasts?

**Code:**

```
batteryLevelTimeStamps = new LinkedList<String>();
BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        int level = -1;
        if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
            level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
        }

        batteryLevel = level + "%";
        batteryLevelTimeStamps.add("At time: " + new Date().toString() + " the battery level is:" +batteryLevel); 
        out.print("At time: " + new Date().toString() + " the battery level is:" +batteryLevel + " in onCreate\n");
    }
};

IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
```

Comment: I hope you're aware that waking up every 10 minutes will significantly affect your battery life.

Comment: I'm aware, I am testing the characteristics of battery drain. The phone will actually be awake for the entire duration of the test.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at using the AlarmManager. You can set an alarm when the phone boots up, and after you receive that alarm, you can check the battery and set another alarm 10 minutes in the future.

Using AlarmManager is better than your own thread because

- It allows the phone to go to low power usage mode during the ten minute wait
- At the end of 10 minutes, it will wake up the phone if it is currently in that low power state.

Comment: I will look into AlarmManager for the 10 minute wakeups. I have been thinking about it and I would actually prefer to get the time whenever the battery level changes, and the phone will be awake for the entire test anyway, can you give me an idea of how I would go about keeping the broadcast receiver alive?

Comment: Don't know about that one. :(